# RF Link with APC220 between two PIC16F877's

Tags: pic, wireless, rf, uart, microchip

I am attempting to communicate through a RF link between two PIC16F877's using APC220 Radio Transients. When the PIC UART's are connected with wires between TX and RX they communicate just fine, but will not communicate with APC220 module. I have the APC220 modules connected as in this diagram from the user manual.

GND and VCC connected,
EN Disconnected,
TX and RX connected,
SET as High,

The APC220 modules settings are being written and read correctly using RF-Magic. 
The baud rate for PIC UART and APC220 are set for 9600.
Air rate 9600,
No Parity,
Same Net ID and Different Node ID's,
434MHZ.

I have read what seems like every document ever written on these RF units but can not for the life of me get them to communicate. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm no expert but...try setting the air rate higher if you are using the transmit buffer.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried this and did not get any results. I am not using the buffer aniway.

Comment: I didn't read anything about the straight-in and out way of sending data but, from experience.... if you are using the transmitter and receiver as "dumb devices" you may have to send a data preamble to the receiver before it is able to properly "lock-in" to your transmission. Do a web trawl for this mode of operation on the APC220 - it might prove useful

Comment: Problem solved! I removed all connections apart from GND, VCC, TX and RX. I set one PIC to only transmit and one to recieve. The two APC220's communicate just fine between two PIC UART ports with just these 4 connections. Serial communication in both directions will be a matter of programming it accordingly in MPLAB.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help though

Comment: Is EN an enable pin, and active high or low?